# First show, after hide via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this HTML structure:

```
 <div id="side-menu">
            <ul>
            <li><img src="img/once_sonra.png"></img></li>
            <li><img src="img/online_destek.png"></img></li>
            <li><img src="img/sizi_arayalim.png"></img></li>
            </ul>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#side-menu {
    display:block;
    z-index:20;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:76px;
}
```

I want, when click my page show this items and after hide with animate effect but i dont know how can i do? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that a single click should show and then hide, or that the first click should show and the next click should hide? _"when click my page"_ - What, _anywhere_ on the page? Have you looked into jQuery's `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` or [other animation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)?

Comment: @nnnnnn entire my web page, show this items and after hide (no click on this items, automatic) I don't want fade effect.

Comment: So what effect do you want? "With animate effect" is pretty vague.

Comment: Like this http://www.facebook.com/TheFamousGrouseTurkiye/app_203505773004141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide the menu initially
    $("#side-menu").hide();
    $(document).click(function() {
        // on click show and then hide menu with animation
        $("#side-menu").slideDown().delay(500).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dhVzq/

If you don't like the slide effect jQuery gives you [several other options](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

Comment: Thank you, it's working but i don't want click function. when i come to site, automatic give effect.

Comment: @user1750573 Then just remove the `.click()` part and put everything in `$(document).ready(function() {});`.

Comment: Yes, what @irrelephant (nice user name!) said. Also, if you don't want a click function then don't write a question that says "when click my page"...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to bind to the `click` event of the page:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $sideMenu = $('#side-menu'),
        itemClicked = false; // Use to determine whether an item was clicked

    $sideMenu.hide();

    // Catch clicks on the document
    $(document.body).click(function(e) {

        // Check if the menu is visible
        if (!$sideMenu.is(':visible')) {
            $sideMenu
                .stop(true) // Cancel any animation from a previous click
                .show(); // Show the menu

            // Set a timer to hide the menu after 5 seconds if nothing was clicked
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (!itemClicked) {
                    $sideMenu.slideUp(); // Hide the menu with the slideUp effect
                }
                itemClicked = false; // Reset the flag for next time round
            }, 5000); 
        }
    });

    // Catch clicks on menu items
    $sideMenu.click(function(e) {
        itemClicked = true;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo. I've updated the fiddle with my revised example based on your comments: http://jsfiddle.net/kelervin/faxcn/1/

Comment: Looks like @nnnnnn's answer is what you want, but I'll leave this here for posterity